# Scala function which extracts Class[_] out of generic

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

So what I want to do:

```
def foo(clazz: Class[_]): Unit = {
  val int = classOf[Int]
  val str = classOf[String]
  val opt = classOf[Option[_]]
  clazz match {
    case `int` => println("INT!")
    case `str` => println("STRING!")
    case `opt` => foo(clazz.getTheTypeOutOfGeneric) // <- I think you get the idea 
  }
}
```

For the given `clazz: Class[_ :< Option[_]]` I would want to find type with which it was created, so in the end I would get `INT!` when running with type `Option[Int]`.  How can I do it? Do I have to use reflections?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: `Class` does not carry any information about type parameters.

So for example

```
classOf[Option[Int]] eq classOf[Option[String]]
```

will return `true`. Note that the operator `eq` checks for referential equality, so these two are actually the exact same object!

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Chlt2kF/0)

Even with reflection you won't be able to get information which is just not there.

---

I would recommend to move away from using `Class` values and instead use type parameters and type classes for ad-hoc polymorphism. The exact solution depends on what you are effectively trying to do.

But, here is an example on how type classes work:

```
def get[F[_], A](a: F[A])(implicit ex: Extractor[A]): Unit = ex.extract

trait Extractor[A] {
  def extract: Unit
}

implicit val intExtractor = new Extractor[Int] {
  def extract: Unit = println("I am doing something for Int!")
}

implicit val strExtractor = new Extractor[String] {
  def extract: Unit = println("I am doing something for String!")
}

val a = Some(1)

get(a)
```

Output:

```
I am doing something for Int!
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/6a9Rfys/0)

For more information I would recommend reading [The Type Astronaut’s
Guide to Shapeless](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.pdf), which (apart from teaching you about Shapeless) helps you understand more general aspects of generic programming in Scala.

I hope this helps.

Comment: To add to this. shapeless has ways to capture that information. but often it really isn't necessary to do this

Comment: @DominicEgger directly from the `Class` object?

Comment: oh no I was expand on your explanation to go with type parameters which is the way to go!

Comment: also  `TypeCase`

Answer (score 0):

You can't that information from `Class` because of type erasure. You would need a `ClassTag` for that:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def foo[T : TypeTag](clazz: Class[T]) = clazz match {
   ...
   case `opt` => foo(typeOf[T].typeArgs.head)
   ...
}
```

But before you do this, do check out `Type` and `TypeTag`, and other goodies in `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` - more than likely, you will find a simpler and a more elegant way to implement what you need with that stuff, than passing raw `Class`'es around.